# Dynamic tabs using Bootstrap and php only showing data from 1st tab

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, tabs

So i'm trying to fill tabs with data  using php/mysql. It works fine for the first tab (the active one), but when pressing the other tabs, the content doesn't change. I keep seeing the same data of the first tab shown on the other tabs and it does not change !

When the page was static, i added many tabs to check if they are working, and yeah it worked fine. every tab has it own static data.
But after adding php, the only data i'm receiving are those of the first tab!
Here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Burger Code</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6ab5be8f07.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css?v=1.1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Holtwood+One+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container site">
            <h1 class="text-logo"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i> BURGER CODE <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></h1>
            <?php 
            require 'admin/database.php';
            echo ' <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:none;">';
            $db = Database::connect();
            $statement = $db->query('SELECT * FROM categories');
            $categories = $statement->fetchAll();
            foreach($categories as $category){
                if($category['id'] == '1')
                    echo '<li class="nav-item" id="item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#'.$category['id'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a></li>';
                else
                    echo '<li class="nav-item" id="item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#'.$category["id"].'">'.$category['name'].'</a></li>';
            }
                echo "</ul>";

                echo '<div class="tab-content">';

                foreach($categories as $category){
                    if($category['id'] == '1')
                        echo '<div class="tab-pane active" id="' . $category['id'] .'">';
                    else
                        echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="' . $category['id'] . '">';

                    echo '<div class="row">';
                    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.category = ?");
                    $statement->execute(array($category['id']));
                    while($item = $statement->fetch())
                    {
                        echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 box">
                                <div class="img-thumbnail" >
                                    <img src="images/' . $item["image"] . '" alt="..." style="border:none; " class="img-thumbnail">
                                    <div class="price">' . number_format($item['price'], 2, '.','') . '</div>
                                    <div id="caption">
                                        <h4>' . $item['name'] . '</h4>
                                        <p>' . $item['description'] . '</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-order" role="button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Commander</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>
                    </div>';

                }
                echo '</div>';
                Database::disconnect();
                ?>



            ?>
        </div>  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a few errors regarding expected syntax and duplicate `id` fields. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/   ... In particular what I noticed, though there may be other errors, this part here `<li class="nav-item" id="item">` doesn't supposed to get the `id`, it's the anchor that is nested that is supposed to get the `id` and that `id` should be unique, not "item" each time.